# Can I use my existing Canon lenses on an EF-M camera body?

Tags: canon, lens-mount, lens-adapter, canon-m

Canon recently introduced the [Canon EOS M](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/eos_m_ef_m_22mm_stm_kit), mirrorless interchangeable lens camera. It uses a new EF-M mount and is available as a kit with an EF-M lens in some regions. I have existing EF and EF-S lenses from my Canon 40D, will these work fully on the EF-M mount camera?

Comment: you might want to look at this newsletter from canon, featuring all the M product range.
[Canon newsletter](http://canonctd.cusa.canon.com/ctd/lu?RID=1-6UGICR&CON=1-2MJ3-211&PRO=&AID=&relayIds=T&OID=1-6SA9F8&CID=1-6SA9G2&COID=1-6SA9G7&T=http://www.usa.canon.com/app/emails/eosjuly12v?WT.mc_id=EM1207EO05005&Z=83934f45aae38512a0c583867c2289f1&TN=Web%20Version&RT=Clicked%20On%20URL)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Canon also announced the [Canon Mount Adapter EF-EOS M](http://www.canon-europe.com/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/EF_Lenses/EF-M/Mount_Adapter_EF_EOS_M/) when they announced the EOS M camera. The adapter is said to be available in October 2012 for $199 USD. It is compatible with the full range of EF and EF-S lenses that are currently available. This also includes the full range of third-party lenses that currently work with the available EOS bodies.

The adapter specifically extends the EF-M flange distance(bayonet to the sensor) from 18mm to 44mm that the other Canon DSLRs have.

One nice feature of the adapter is that it has a built in tripod mount. This can come in handy when mounting a larger lens to the smaller EOS M body. One example of a very large full size lens being used with the adapter can be found [here](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/46625/canon-eos-m-review-hands-on), where they test it with an EF 800mm prime lens.

So any lens that you have that works with the Canon 40D should have no problem with the EF-M mount EOS M camera body, using the adapter of course. This means full functionality such as autofocus and lens information. I have yet to test out the implementation to see how autofocus actually performs with this setup, but early reports seem to be positive from what I have found.

Answer (score 0):

Canon says yes. Some big lenses are going to look really silly on that tiny body.

The M has a different type of auto-focus, more like video cameras and less like other DSLRs. Many pocket cameras have really slow auto-focus.

I'd wait until some reviewers have had a chance to actually test the production models and see if the AF performance is good enough.

Comment: I think that all but the smallest prime lenses and the new EF-M lenses are going to look silly!

Comment: extreme silliness: http://www.canonrumors.com/2012/07/canon-eos-m-ef-800-f5-6l-is/